# Script to map columns in two csv files

Tags: csv, awk, mapping

I am trying to map columns values in two .csv files. Its a high dimensional data file but I am only concerned about mapping and adding a new field in the second .csv file.

My File1 .csv files have labels: #Sender ID, #Type;
My File2 .csv files have labels: #Sender ID, #Label;

What I am trying to do is if #sender ID(File1) = sender ID(File2), then add a new column in file 2, defining the type. Because sender ID is randomized and repetitive, it's not possible to simply copy paste the #type->#Label column in file 2.

I looked into "awk" command line but not sure how to proceed with it and also if that's will help to resolve the issue or not. Please suggest.

File1.csv(Input)
`#Sender ID,#Recieve ID, #Noise, #Position, #Type, #velocity
23,value,value,value, 1, value
43,value,value,value, 2, value
12,value,value,value, 1, value
78,value,value,value, 0, value
43,value,value,value, 2, value`

File2.csv(Input)
`#Sender ID,#Acc,#Angle,#Label
23,value, value, NaN
43,value,value, NaN
12,value,value, NaN
78, value,value,NaN
43, value,value, NaN`

File2.csv(Expected Output)
`#Sender ID,#Acc,#Angle,#Label
23,value, value, 1
43,value, value, 2
12,value, value, 1
78,value, value, 0
43,value, value, 2`

Original File 1 Headers:
`sender,    attackerType,   messageID`

Original File 2 Headers:
`type, rcvTime, sendTime,   sender, messageID,  pos__001,   pos__002,   pos__003,   pos_noise__001, pos_noise__002, pos_noise__003, noise__001, noise__002, noise__003, spd__001,   spd__002,   spd__003,   spd_noise__001, spd_noise__002, spd_noise__003, RSSI,   Label`

Expected File 2 Headers should match the #sender with File 1 and then update the #Label field (label attribute is originally empty) with the corresponding #attackerType.

Here what I did:`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}

> NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next}
>   {$4=a[$22]}1' File1.csv File2.csv`

Remember the number of rows is not same for both the files.

Comment: `awk` seems like the best tool for this task.  However, your problem description is lacking sample input/output

Comment: Thank you for responding @karakfa.I have added a sample input and expected output file. Hope that helps.

Comment: Please post the file contents in the body of the text and do formatting with `{}`

Comment: Just did it. Let me know if that doesn't help.Thank you.

Comment: Here comes the art of asking help.  Your sample input/output should cover edge cases that you're warning about.  Here just setting output=file1 will do the trick.  Also, not clear whether headers are part of the files or not.

Comment: Here the output file != file1 because of the dimensionality. Also, I forgot to add that headers are included in the .CSV files.

Comment: It's literally matching the sender ID from both the files and then map the #type field from file1 in the #label field in file2. Not sure, how can I use awk in solving this problem.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'BEGIN   {FS=OFS=","} 
       NR==FNR {a[$1]=$5; next} 
       FNR>1   {$4=a[$1]}1' file1 file2
```

if your delimiters have uneven spaces around you may need to play with the delimiters.

If there are extra keys in file2, the value `NAN` will be removed.  To prevent that you may want to add `&& ($1 in a)` to `FNR>1` condition.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried running the code but I am getting file2 printed out in the terminal as it is. No addition/mapping from File1.

Comment: that is odd!  `$4=a[$1]` should overwrite the 4th field.  To test remove `FNR>1` condition (header will be wrong).

Comment: No luck. Let me add the original headers {} in for the files. Maybe that will help.

Comment: Why did you put `$22`, which column is the key in File2?

Comment: I had $22 for #Label column. Key is $4 is sender in File 2.

Comment: I got it working. Thank you so much for helping out. awk is indeed the life savior :)